# How to get the file object from a Django Post Request without using a form and save it to a model?

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, request

I am using a new FormData() and appending jsonvalue and a file to be sent in a POST request to Django backend . I can see the json data but not the file object in the backend. I am using Fetch API to post the request.

```
<input id='fileid' type='file' hidden  name="" @change="onFileChange"/>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="Add comments .." v-model="activeChatArea"></textarea> 




async replyComment(request_id) {

var data = this.activeChatArea
var attachment = this.activeFile
console.log(attachment)
this.activeChatArea = ""
console.log(data)
const csrfToken = this.getCookie('csrftoken')
var formData = new FormData();
var file = $('#fileid').prop('files')[0];
console.log("FILE....")
console.log(file)
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({

    request_id: request_id,
    comment: data,


})
formData.append("fileData", file)
formData.append("textData", jsonData)
var response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/comments/", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
    },


});

var data = await response.json();
console.log("got comments")
if (response.ok) {

    this.loadActiveChatMessages(request_id)
    console.log("COMMENT is OK")
    console.log(data)

} else {
    console.log(response)
}
},
```

When I do a `print(request.POST)` then i can see the data like this :

```
<QueryDict: {'textData': ['{"request_id":"8769c452-53f1-4f14-80b0-7d2818e133e6","comment":"sdfsdfsdfsdfsdf"}']}>
```

When I do a `print(request._files)` then I can see something like this:

```
<MultiValueDict: {'fileData': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: icons8-search-16.png (image/png)>]}>
```

**What I actually want to do is  :**

I would manually like to create the model object and save it

```
MyModel.objects.create(file=fileRecivedfromRequest,text=textRecvdfromRequest)
```

Comment: What you get in request.data?

Comment: @ТаалайДюшебеков AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'

Comment: what about request.FILES?